# Cannot connect to test database after upgrading to django 3.1

Tags: python, django

I am trying to migrate a django app from 3.0.11 to 3.1.

I can run the app without any issues. But I cannot run tests anymore.

The following error is thrown when running `python manage.py test`

`django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection e doesn't exist`

This is from my settings.py:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': config("DB_NAME", default='postgres'),
        'USER': config('DB_USER', default='postgres'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD', default='postgres'),
        'HOST': config('DB_HOST', default='postgres'),
    }
}
```

Full stacktrace:

```py
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 172, in ensure_defaults
    conn = self.databases[alias]
KeyError: 'e'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 53, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 698, in run_tests
    self.run_checks(databases)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 636, in run_checks
    call_command('check', verbosity=self.verbosity, databases=databases)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 168, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/check.py", line 63, in handle
    self.check(
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 34, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1264, in check
    *cls._check_fields(**kwargs),
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1343, in _check_fields
    errors.extend(field.check(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 2361, in check
    *super().check(**kwargs),
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1724, in check
    *super().check(**kwargs),
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 203, in check
    *self._check_backend_specific_checks(**kwargs),
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 345, in _check_backend_specific_checks
    errors.extend(connections[alias].validation.check_field(self, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    self.ensure_defaults(alias)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mysite/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 174, in ensure_defaults
    raise ConnectionDoesNotExist("The connection %s doesn't exist" % alias)
django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection e doesn't exist
```

Did anyone experience a similar problem and can help me fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found the issue. The crash resulted from a single "misconfigured" test.

I had a test which looked like this:

```py
class MyTest(SimpleTestCase):
   databases = 'other'

   def test_something(self):
      pass
```

I guess the attribute `databases` was ignored before Django 3.1, in order to fix it i had to write
`databases = {"other"}`

(This also does require a database configuration in `settings.py` called *other* )